# Custom components on different versions

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

I'm using ActionBarSherlock to get the ActionBar on older versions of Android. However, the buttons and text field are still different below ICS. If I made a custom button or EditText, would they look the same on Android 2.x an 4.x? 
Edit: And are there any good, simple tutorials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Asset Studio Tools](http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/index.html) to create a harmonic 4.X UI design

Comment: How do I then apply these custom elements?

Comment: just paste the content from the archives into your project, the folders should be equal